# How to fix RPCFailedError when deployed simple upload code in flexible environment in google cloud

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, upload

I have Laravel php app deployed in google app engine in flexible environment 
we need to upload directly to google storage large files so I follow this instructions
[Allowing Users to Upload Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload)

this work fine in the standard environment with this source code 
[Source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/6d6757ee1df71e22ded52c2c78edf58786a99961/appengine/php55/storage)

but in my case I have to deploy my app in flexible environment to upload greater that 1000 file when I put the code which in 
[Source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/6d6757ee1df71e22ded52c2c78edf58786a99961/appengine/php55/storage)
 in my flexible environment with this configuration in app.yaml

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: ./
```

it gave me some errors: I solved them all by putting some packages in composer be be like that

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "^1.3",
        "twig/twig": "~1.8|~2.0",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.7|3.0.*",
        "google/appengine-php-sdk": "^1.9",
        "ext-bcmath": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "google/cloud-tools": "^0.6",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

and I set some values for upload_max_filesize in

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
php_value upload_max_filesize 100
```

this to fix problem happened only in flexible environment 
when try to do this code

```
private static function getUploadMaxFileSizeInBytes() {
    $val = trim(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
    $unit = strtolower(substr($val, -1));
    switch ($unit) {
      case 'g':
        $val *= 1024;
        // Fall through
      case 'm':
        $val *= 1024;
        // Fall through
      case 'k':
        $val *= 1024;
        break;
    }
    return intval($val);
  }
```

the value of $val comes like '100M' which give error when try to do this operation

```
$val *= 1024;
```

Finally I get this error 
[image: the error]
so What I'm doing I need this code https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/6d6757ee1df71e22ded52c2c78edf58786a99961/appengine/php55/storage'>Source code
 which working in standard environment to work in flexible environment so I can integrate it with my Laravel project

I'm using google app engine with flexible environment to upload directly to google storage

for flexible environment in google app engine app.yaml

```
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: ./
```

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "^1.3",
        "twig/twig": "~1.8|~2.0",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.7|3.0.*",
        "google/appengine-php-sdk": "^1.9",
        "ext-bcmath": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "google/cloud-tools": "^0.6",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
php_value upload_max_filesize 100
```

app.php

```
<?php


# [START use_cloud_storage_tools]
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
# [END use_cloud_storage_tools]
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// create the Silex application
$app = new Application();
$app->register(new TwigServiceProvider());
$app['twig.path'] = [ __DIR__ ];

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    # [START user_upload]
    $options = ['gs_bucket_name' => 'fvappcloud'];
    $upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload/handler', $options);
    die($upload_url);//for just test
    # [END user_upload]
    $params['upload_url'] = $upload_url;
    return $app['twig']->render('storage.html.twig', $params);
});


/**
 * Handle an uploaded file.
 * @see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload#implementing_file_uploads
 */
$app->post('/upload/handler', function () use ($app) {
    $my_bucket ='fvappcloud';
    # [START move_uploaded_file]
    $file_name = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "gs://${my_bucket}/${file_name}");
    # [END move_uploaded_file]
    return sprintf('Your file "%s" has been uploaded.', $file_name);
});

return $app;
```

index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// Install composer dependencies with "composer install"
// @see http://getcomposer.org for more information.
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require __DIR__ . '/app.php';

// change this to your bucket name!
$app['bucket_name'] = 'fvappcloud';

// Run the app!
// use "gcloud app deploy" or run locally with dev_appserver.py
$app['debug'] = true;
$app->run();
```

storage.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Storage Example</h1>

    <div>
        <h3>
            User Uploads
            [<a href="https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload">docs</a>]:
        </h3>

        {# [START user_upload_form] #}
        <form action="{{ upload_url }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            Files to upload: <br>
           <input type="file" name="uploaded_files" multiple>
           <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
        {# [END user_upload_form] #}
    </div>


</html>
```

I expect to give signed url to upload diretly to google storage

Comment: In the php.ini you do not use any unit of measure. I am not sure if its possible

Comment: @GiacomoM that's right to solve a problem 
the value of $val comes like '100M' which give error when try to do this operation I will give you screen of that problem moment

$val *= 1024;

Comment: @GiacomoM

https://prntscr.com/omhfhn
if it has value and unit then $val= '100G' for example then $val*=1024 will give this error A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution to this? Will you please share.

Comment: @JamesShisiah I can not found a solution yet but i made work around for that I made instance for uploading files in standard environment just for upload and my main app stay in flexible environment and when upload in main app interface I send file with ajax to the upload script in  standard environment

Comment: @AhmedHelalAhmed Perfect idea; that's exactly what I thinking of doing. Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1):

The `$val` variable is now something like "100M", so it contains a letter.
If you want to multiply that variable for a number, you have to remove the letter.

This is the edited function:

```
private static function getUploadMaxFileSizeInBytes() {
    $val = trim(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
    $unit = strtolower(substr($val, -1));
    // RIGHT HERE $val contains a letter, we have to remove it
    $val = str_ireplace($unit, "", $val);
    switch ($unit) {
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
            // Fall through
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
            // Fall through
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
            break;
    }
    return intval($val);
}
```

Comment: This is not my implementation it's belongs to google not me. it's just package in vendors folder so I can not change it [GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-sdk](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-sdk/blob/master/google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php)

Comment: and that's the reason I set it as a value only without unit

Comment: @AhmedHelalAhmed I got it, but I do not know if apache can read a value without unit of measure. As far as I know you have to use unit of measure in php.ini

Comment: I'm using google app engine and it pass through this function when i set it with value only in .htaccess and give another error https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yzCh.png where I can do no thing and idea?

Comment: First of all you have to be really sure you can use only value in php.ini or in .htaccess. After that you can try to solve the error.